# Filtering Wordpress custom post types with custom date field and with Russian format

Tags: wordpress

I want to filter custom post type with custom field (date) from current date, which has format like this: 21.05.2011.
So it should output upcoming games (which is my custom post type).
My query is here:

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>'game',
                                             'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
                                             'posts_per_page' => 23, 
                                             'meta_key' => 'date',
                                             'meta_compare' => '>=',
                                             'meta_value' => date("d.m.Y"),
                                             'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                                             'order' => 'ASC'
)); ?>
```

It outputs smth games with dates like this (current date is 21.10.2011):
23.02.2011, 24.02.2011, 25.04.2011.....

I need only upcoming games, for example 24.10.2011, 01.11.2011...

Answer (score 2):

When WP_Query (the class behind `query_posts()` compares these dates it's treating them as string literals. With that in mind, 21.10.2011 is less than 23.02.2011 since 23 > 21.

You would be best off storing your dates in a more conventional YYYY-MM-DD format (so that 2011-10-21 would come before 2011-10-24), then format the output using [PHP's date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

**Example:**

```
$date = '2011-10-21';
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
# Output => '21.10.2011'
```